# Замена символов переноса на <br>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть `<span>Текст1\nТекст2</span>`

Нужно на JavaScript заменить `\n` на перенос строки, чтобы в браузере вывелось:

```
Текст1
Текст2
```

Я так понял тут не просто `<br>` replace-ом вставить нужно, а ещё что-то по тегам.
Предложите самый простой путь.

Comment: _так понял тут не просто br replace-ом вставить нужно, а ещё что-то по тегам_ - откуда такое предположение?

Comment: можно, кстати вообще ничего не менять, просто поставить: `white-space: pre;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы переданная внутрь элемента строка распарсилась как html, используйте [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) сеттер:

```js
let elem=document.querySelector('span')
elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g,'<br>')
```

```html
<span>Луна\nсъела\nпеченьку</span>
```

Или если у вас реальные переносы строк, а не в виде текста:

```js
let elem=document.querySelector('span')
elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')
```

```html
<span>Луна
съела
печеньку</span>
```

Или без `<br>`ов:

```js
let elem=document.querySelector('span')
elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g,'\n')
```

```css
span{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<span>Луна\nсъела\nпеченьку</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var foo = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  if (foo[i].textContent.indexOf("\n")) {
    foo[i].innerHTML = foo[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>");
  }
}
```

```html
<span>some text \n some text</span>
```